# Qt : cannot connect signal and slot in 2 custom classes

Tags: qt, signals-slots

I have problems with signal -> slot between custom classes

The definition of parameters class

```
class Parameters : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        //public stuff
    private slots:
       void NewValue(int Index, QVariant Value);

    private:
    //private stuff
}
```

The definition of qNumedit class

```
class QNumEdit : public QLineEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT


    public:
        //public stuff
    signals:
        void ValueChanged(int ,QVariant);

    private:
        //private stuff
}
```

In QnumEdit i emit a signal

```
emit ValueChanged(1,2);`
```

this is my slot function

```
void Parameters::NewValue(int Index, QVariant Value)
{
    qDebug() << "NewValue " << Index << Value;
}
```

this is a static test function

```
void test(int Index, QVariant Value)
{
    qDebug() << "test " << Index << Value;
}
```

This is the way I connect both

```
QNumEdit* e = new QNumEdit(QMetaType::Double, i);
QObject::connect(e,&QNumEdit::ValueChanged,this,&Parameters::NewValue); //DOES NOT WORK
QObject::connect(e,&QNumEdit::ValueChanged,test);   //THIS WORKS OK!!!`
```

The slot function  NewValue is never triggered
The static function Test is triggered

When I do the same thing, but the receiving class is my mainwindow, everything is OK.

Any idea ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.  What does `this` refer to in the relevant `connect` call shown?  Are you sure it doesn't refer to a locally scoped `Parameters` instance that will be destroyed *before* the `valueChanged` signal is emitted?

Comment: The most likely solution is that the object refered in the connection as `this` gets deleted and hence the connection gets disconnected. Aren't you creating the object on the stack by mistake and therefore deleting it at the end of the scope? This is a very frequent beginners' mistake.

Comment: As mentioned above, please post your code. what is the parent widget? how is it intervened? if you want to change something by entering it, a key press event might make sense. it is unclear what your goal is. Also, you should never start a custom class with Q... this could lead to irritation later on

Comment: suggestion: try an alternative signal/slot implementation and see if it works.

Comment: Problem solved. I did create the object on the stack... Shame on me! Thanks for the hints above!